# how to calculate date period in two days using c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a date in my SQL Server database, I want to calculate how many dates on that day to today date. Imagine I create an invoice in `5/31/2019` and it saves in database and today `(6/5/2019)` I'm going a create payment receipt for it, now I want to calculate the date period.

Comment: no i wanna get one date from data base and other date is today date..

Comment: @ShaniRathnayake When u say u want to calculate 'date period', what does that mean? can you show your expected output for the scenario that you have mentioned in your question?

Comment: @akg179 when (5/31/2019) - (6/5/2019) the answer should be 5 days

Comment: ok guys thanks for help me. i found answer.

Comment: while (Dr2.Read())
                {


                    textBox1.Text = Dr2["Date"].ToString();

                    DateTime s1 = DateTime.Parse(TxtReceiptD.Text);
                    DateTime s2 = DateTime.Parse(Dr2["Date"].ToString());

                    
                    TimeSpan  T = s1 - s2;

                    int days =  (int)T.TotalDays;

                    TxtMonthIntAmt.Text = days.ToString();


                }

Comment: @ShaniRathnayake Here you need do `int days = (s2  - s1).Days`

Answer (score 3):

As example:

```
DateTime StartDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2);
DateTime EndDate = DateTime.Now;
double days = (EndDate - StartDate).TotalDays;
Debug.WriteLine(days);
```

Comment: OP is trying to get int where he need difference between only  `Date`

Answer (score 1):

If you have two `DateTime` and you want to calculate in between these two dates, the you can substract Dates and get [`Days`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.day?view=netframework-4.8) out of it

Something like,

```
DateTime ReceiptDate = new DateTime(2019, 05, 31)
int difference = (DateTime.Now  - ReceiptDate).Days //ReceiptDate is type of DateTime which is converted from database value
Console.WriteLine(difference);
```

Output:

> 5

POC : [.net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rWh6Ys)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could think of would be to assign each day a numeric value, making sure to account for leap years. For instance, January 8th would be 8, as it's the 8th day of the year. February 8th would be 39. And to calculate how many days had passed, just subtract the first date from the second. So from Jan 8 to Feb 8 is (39-8) = 31 days.

Comment: i wanna c# code for it

Comment: Wait, you want someone to actually write it for you?  Sorry, I thought you were just wondering how you would go about it.